# How to iterate over a list of data-frames in R

Tags: r, coding-style, dataframe

I have a list in R that contains several data frames. I want to iterate over the data frames and calculate the min/max of a value from the data frame. Here's the code that I have right now:

```
firstname = names(dats)[1]
xlim = c( min( dats[[firstname]][,xlab] ), max( dats[[firstname]][,xlab] ) )
for ( name in names(dats) ) {
   xlim = c( min(xlim[1],dats[[name]][,xlab]), max(xlim[2],dats[[name]][,xlab]) )
}
```

This seems ugly to me, as it requires a lot of code to do something very simple. Is there a more canonical way to do this in R?

Comment: +1 for the Q. It's not so much that there's a lot of code, it's more the fact that it is completely unreadable. There has to be a better way than that for the sake of sanity.

Comment: Could you provide some example data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to extract the `xlab` column out of all the data-frames, and `unlist` to combine into one vector, then take the `min` or `max`:

```
xlab <- 'a'
dats <- list( df1 = data.frame(a=sample(1:3), b = sample(11:13)),
              df2 = data.frame(a=sample(1:3), b = sample(11:13)))

>  min( unlist( lapply( dats, '[', xlab ) ) )
[1] 1
>  max( unlist( lapply( dats, '[', xlab ) ) )
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you combine the data frames from the list of data frames into one data frame? I would use the `plyr` package and `rbind.fill`, which would allow the data frames to have mismatched columns as long as the column of interest is named the same in all data frames.

```
library(plyr)
df.orig <- data.frame(one = rep(1:4, each = 4), two = 1:16)
df.list <- dlply(df.orig, "one")
df.new <- rbind.fill(df.list)
xlim <- with(df.new, c(min(two), max(two)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, heres something to do with plyr:

```
dats <- list( df1 = data.frame(a=sample(1:3), b = sample(11:13)),
              df2 = data.frame(a=sample(1:3), b = sample(11:13)))

library(plyr)

xlim <- adply(do.call("rbind",dats),2,function(x)c(min(x),max(x)))
    names(xlim)=c("xlab","min","max")

xlim
  xlab min max
1    a   1   3
2    b  11  13
```

Gives per variable the minimum and maximum collapsed over all data frames in the list.

EDIT: shortened the code abit. I do assume that each dataframe contains the same number of columns in the same order.